# Is this a logical expression?

Tags: python, intervals

Which of the following is a valid logical expression that tests to see if a number is in the interval [0, 1) ?

I answered `num >= 0 or num < 1`

I think the [ includes 0 and numbers above* it?

Comment: Think about some numbers outside the range. Is it true that 5 >= 0 or 5 < 1?

Comment: "I think the [ includes 0 and numbers below it" - that's not what the [ means. I don't know where you got the "and numbers below it" idea.

Comment: `or` definitely isn't the right operator either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'[' means greater than or equal to ')' means less than in standard interval notation.
The correct expression would be num >= 0 **and** num < 1. The or would allow any number greater than 0 or less than 1 to be valid.

Comment: Shorter version in Python: `0 <= num < 1`

Answer (score 0):

`[]` means 'included' and `()` means excluded. As in your case, [0, 1) means all the numbers in the range of 0 to 1, with 0 included and 1 excluded. So, the condition will become `num >= 0 and num < 1`. `or` means any of the conditions is True. This will include all the numbers all the numbers greater than or equal to zero and also all the numbers less than 1, whereas `and` will allow only the numbers which satisfy both the conditions.

Comment: thank you! Was focusing on one condition being true but "and" is definitely needed